# Parse location based query not working after data migration

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

Parse query `withinKilometers()` is not working after I migrated the database to my own mongoDB server (No error, but response is empty).

The issue is being discussed in [github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/607)

But they say it is issue of mongoDB version.
I tried using mongo 3.0.11 , 3.0.9 and 3.0.0

A workaround mentioned is by using cloud code, but the query fails in the cloud too.

Any one have some other workaround please help as the last date of parse data migration is around the corner.

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm not sure it's related to MongoDB either but haven't found a solution.

Comment: Please try the solution, it worked for me. Hope it does for you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to create index for our database column for mongoDB to support geoQuerry, by default it will not support it seems.

Solution:

```
db.prod.createIndex({ "location": "2d" })
```

Where prod is my collection name and location is name of column which stores geo location (GeoPoint)

Few more details about the issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1592)

Thanks